# How to show a view controller For incoming call, even device is also locked and application is in background state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I'm currently working on iOS Voip App development, like skype,viber.

Now my problem is when my Application is in Foreground, it shows when incoming call came.But the app is in background state and device is also locked, I want to show my incomingCallViewController for answering the call without unlocking the phone.

How to show a view controller when application is in background state and device is also get locked?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a push notification to display an incoming call. When the user taps on this notification, open your app and show your ViewController. WhatsApp is using this method.

(Note that using push notifications for your app requires Apple developer membership.)

Comment: This is correct I'have implemented but how we should do if screen is locked, we know pretty much answer but question is how?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the CallKit framework, the app can access incoming calls with the native UI, even when the app is in the background or terminated states.

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to achieve what you mentioned in your query. When the system event for incoming call is triggered your app will be sent in the background mode automatically and you can't show your viewController.

Comment: then how normal incoming call screen appears when call came,even device is locked?

Comment: It's part of the OS itself and operating system invokes the viewcontroller on that system event.